# How to redirect in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is my first time working with .htaccess and i'm absolutely clueless...

I need to create a .htaccess file, which would redirect from URL to another URL.

Let's say user types the following URL: http://localhost/htaccess_test/os/windows/8 ...when he does, he would get redirected to http://localhost/htaccess_test/os/windows/os.php?type=windows&version=8 .

I also need to create a os.php file, which lists values of the parameters in URL (type and version of operating system).

Any help will be much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^os/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /os.php?type=$1&version=$2 [R=301,L]
```

**os.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['type']) && isset($_GET['version'])){

    echo "Tip OS: " . $_GET['type'] . "<br>";
    echo "Verzija OS: " . $_GET['version'] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Here is a great resource https://github.com/phanan/htaccess

Comment: i know how to redirect .html to html (etc from index.html to blog.html). is that the same? @cmorrissey

Comment: In which directory your `.php` files are located?

Comment: C:/xampp/htdocs/htaccess_test @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this .htaccess in `htaccess_test/` directory:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^os/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ os.php?type=$1&version=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Assuming `os.php` exists in `htaccess_test/os/windows/` directory

Comment: Yeh i have os.php in that folder. When i go to localhost/htaccess_test/windows/8, i get 404 not found error. Can you see the update of my .htaccess code and my php file a see where the problem is ?

Comment: When i type in http://localhost/htaccess_test/os/windows/8 it should redirect to http://localhost/htaccess_test/os.php?type=windows&version=8 ...i assume this is done by php?(version and type) ...i guess that means WITH "os"

Comment: check my updated answer. You need `Options -MultiViews` at top and remove `/` before `os.php` in target URI.